# How to redirect from a browser to a mobile application without blocking?

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, quasar-framework

Task: there is a mobile application in which a redirect to the browser is performed. In the browser, the user presses another button and proceeds to another browser page. As soon as he goes to the second page in the browser, after a few seconds I need to automatically return the user to the mobile application. My solution: because the application is building with Cordova, I used the [cordova-plugin-customurlscheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme). An android scheme = 'mycoolapp' was created, configured AndroidManifest, etc. according to the documentation. Everything works. Problem: when I make a link

`<a href="mycoolapp://"> Open my app </a>`

and the user clicks on it, the application opens without problems. But I need an automatic redirect without the participation of the user. I tried it like this:

```
 mounted: function () {
    window.open('mycoolapp://', '_system')}
```

opens here in a pop-up window and asks the user to confirm the opening. Otherwise blocks. It is clear that the browser sees this as spam. Can you suggest alternative options? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep the  tag and use JS script to mimic the click action

```
<a id="my-cool-app" href="mycoolapp://"> Open my app </a>

mounted() {
  document.getElementById('my-cool-app').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, do not open in a new window, this will at least remove the need to ask to open the window. You can simply

```
window.location.href = "mycoolapp://"
```

Not sure if there are other dialogs that you are facing, I think you might be seeing the "open link in the app?" kind of dialog too, but I wouldn't be of help with that one. I think it is mandatory?

Comment: thanks for the answer) i tried `window.location.href = "mycoolapp://"` `window.location.replace = ('mycoolapp://')`. these variants did not work. Only a new browser window opens with url: mycoolapp://.  I just want to avoid dialog like "open link in the app?". Simple automatic redirection of the user to the mobile application.